# connection error:I am new in Mongodb and now I face a problem with mongodb when create connection with node js to mongodb atlas display following erro

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
at Object.resolveSRVRecord (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:45:25)
at Object.connect (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:40:36)
at C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:127:23
at Object.maybePromise (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:509:5)
at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:126:24)
at Function.connect (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:194:36)
at mongoConnect (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\util\database.js:6:17)
at Object. (C:\Users\deepa\Desktop\Noddy\Node-JS\Task 3\app.js:34:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)

databse.js

```
const MongoClient=mongodb.MongoClient;
let _db;
//for connecting and storing the connection to the database
const mongoConnect=(callback)=>{
MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://Deepanshu24:******@cluster0.uu6l5.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority').then(client=>{
    console.log('Connected');
    _db=client.db();
    callback();
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})
}
//get access to the connected database if it exist
const getDb=()=>{
    if(!_db){
        return _db;
    }
    return "No DataBase Found"
}
exports.mongoConnect=mongoConnect;
exports.getDb=getDb;
```

Comment: Did you enable the Network Access already?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details and post the connection string as this really does not help.

With that said the error is telling you that you have no host name to the mongoDB, you need to add the host to the connection string e.g https://[urltomongodb]